# Springboot SPEL throws IllegalArgumentException in SecurityFilterChain Bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-el

when our springboot application gets requests with a user token created by an identity server, we get the following error in our SecurityFilterChain Bean:

`Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'authentication.getPrincipal().getSubject() == #userId'`

Code snippet in SecurityFilterChain Bean:

```
.requestMatchers("/**/user/{userId}/**").access(
                                    new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager(
                                        "authentication.getPrincipal().getSubject() == #userId"
                                    )
                                )
```

Because this error only appears on our live system and because it happens in the filterChain, it is hard for us to debug this error.

Might anyone know what the problem with SPEL could be?

Versions:
springboot 3.1.1
java 17
spring security 6.0.3

Comment: Maybe you can share more stack trace around that error?

Answer (score 0):

Well,we found out, hat some requests didnt have an authorization header. this caused this exception because the principal was null.